# Remove nef files that haven't got a corresponding jpg file in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I would like to write a script that searches through a folder and deletes any raw files (`.nef`) that don't have a matching `jpg`. For example,

Folder structure:

```
DSC_0001.nef
DSC_0001.jpg
DSC_0002.nef
DSC_0003.nef
```

The program would delete `DSC_0002.nef` and `DSC_0003.nef`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Are these `*.nef`files in a folder or in subfolders, also?

Comment: In one folder, no subfolders. I will omit /R, as that seems quite dangerous if the script is run in the wrong place

Comment: sorry im trying to test and respond as fast as i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /R %%F IN (*.NEF) DO @IF NOT EXIST "%%~dpnF.jpg" DEL "%%F"
```

Note: the `/R` switch means recursive (i.e. it will continue to run this command throughout the entire directory tree from the directory where it is run from). Omit that switch if you don't want to process subdirectories as well.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: I ran the original, what is the specifier 'n'?

Comment: `n` is for file name; `x` is extension

Comment: Run `for /?` and you will discover @TomWilloughby.

Comment: @Stephan Is this documented anywhere? Couldn't find that in `IF /?`

Comment: @GovindParmar because it's not part of `if`, but part of `cmd` file name handling (see also `dir *.bat` vs `*.bAt`)

Comment: @GovindParmar realized that it may not work now. `%%~nF.jpg` may exist in `%cd%`, but you don't want that.

Comment: @GovindParmar Also from `if /?` it says `IF [NOT] EXIST filename command` (The `/i` switch is described later `IF [/I] string1 compare-op string2 command`)

Comment: @Stephan Removed the `/I` from my answer

Comment: Despite `/R` ,`"%%~nF.jpg"` will only find files in the root folder - you need `"%%~dpnF.jpg"` (full path) for files in subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

A possible `PowerShell` solution:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\nef" -Filter "*.nef" | foreach {
    if( -not (Get-Item $_.FullName.Replace('.nef','.jpg') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){
        $_ | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` to actually make it delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use (for a single folder):

```bat
@echo off

cd to\folder
for %%A IN (*.nef) do (
    if not exist %%~nA.jpg (del %%~fA)
)
```

And for multiple folders, use:

```bat
@echo off

for /R "full_path_to_parent_folder" %%A IN (*.nef) do (
    if not exist %%~dpnA.jpg (del %%~fA)
)
```